# error input expected at most 1 argument, got 3

Tags: python, input, error-handling, turtle-graphics

```
lmoney = (input("Sounds great! How much money would you like to bet on leonardo?($1-$10,000)(Please don't enter $ sign)")
lconfirm = input('Are you sure you want to put $',lmoney, 'on Leonardo?')
```

Whenever I enter a 3 digit number for my input I get an error that says input expected at most 1 argument, got 3. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: According to the documentaion of [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) there is only one argument allowed.

Comment: Your first line has a syntax error. Your parentheses are not balanced.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because of **the commas** in your input-call.
Python interprets those as seperators for **3 different arguments**.

Still you can use variables in your input-call, the best way to do it would be
to use **formatted strings.**

Simply change lconfirm to:

```
lconfirm = input(f'Are you sure you want to put $ {lmoney} on Leonardo?')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to format your strings using the `format` function. The `input` function does in fact only accept one argument and you have provided multiple.

```
lconfirm = input('Are you sure you want to put {} on Leonardo?'.format(lmoney))
```